# get label value from docker inspect

Tags: docker, docker-compose, jq

I had problem to get the value from the map list due to the key has "." inside.

```sh
docker inspect jenkins
```

```json
  Config: {
  ..
      "Labels": {
            "com.docker.compose.config-hash": "85bcf1e0bcd708120185a303e2a8d8e65543c1ec77ec0c6762fc057dc10320aa",
            "com.docker.compose.container-number": "1",
            "com.docker.compose.oneoff": "False",
            "com.docker.compose.project": "new",
            "com.docker.compose.service": "sc2",
            "com.docker.compose.version": "1.5.2"
        }
    }
}
```

I can get map list

```
docker inspect -f {{.Config.Labels}} new_sc2_1
map[com.docker.compose.config-hash:85bcf1e0bcd708120185a303e2a8d8e65543c1ec77ec0c6762fc057dc10320aa com.docker.compose.container-number:1 com.docker.compose.oneoff:False com.docker.compose.project:new com.docker.compose.service:sc2 com.docker.compose.version:1.5.2]
```

But how can I get the project name `new` from key `com.docker.compose.project`

```
docker inspect -f {{.Config.Labels.com.docker.compose.project}} new_sc2_1
<no value>
```

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You can use `index` to get the value of that key (wrapped for readability);

```
docker inspect \
  --format '{{ index .Config.Labels "com.docker.compose.project"}}' \
  new_sc2_1
```

That should give you the name of the project

Comment: FWIW I tried this in PowerShell and had to add the backtick (`) character in front of the inner double quotes to properly escape. \\`"com.docker.compose.project\\`"

Comment: Changed the example to use single quotes for the outer quotes, that should work as well, and then escaping should not be needed (haven't tried on PowerShell)

Comment: Trying to use it in docker-compose for logging driver like this: `loki-external-labels: container_name={{.Name}},cluster=${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME},service={{ index .Config.Labels 'com.docker.compose.service' }}`
What I do wrong if it fails with _loki: could not expand label value_ ?

Answer (score 13):

You could pipe the output of `docker inspect` to `jq`.  Given content like this:

```
...
        "Labels": {
            "com.docker.compose.config-hash": "a804d541a5828f4aaf17df862b650e58ac5bae77b70ff5ebdb2f0f3682326954",
            "com.docker.compose.container-number": "1",
            "com.docker.compose.oneoff": "False",
            "com.docker.compose.project": "postgis",
            "com.docker.compose.service": "postgis",
            "com.docker.compose.version": "1.7.0rc1"
        }
...
```

I can extract an individual label value like this:

```
docker inspect mycontainer |
jq -r '.[0].Config.Labels["com.docker.compose.project"]'
```

Which gets me:

```
postgis
```

Comment: great, is it possible to remove `"` to get `postgis` directly ?

Comment: Sure, just use the `-r` flag in jq.

Comment: thx @SantiagoLapresta @larsks . And I update the answer with `-r` directly.